# Is there a way in an ADO Build Pipeline to only build one of the artifacts?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have an ADO build pipeline that builds three artifacts.  However, while I am developing, I only want one of the artifacts to be built since that is the artifact on which I am working and it takes longer for all of them to build and I don't want to wait.  Can I disable the other artifacts from building?

Comment: Do you mean locally or in the pipeline you want only one artifact?

Comment: @GredH. Does this issue resolved now? If not, please share the latest info about it here.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, you could not use UI to disable some of artifacts which build from one build pipeline. Because we does not provide this feature in VSTS now.

But as workaround, you can use **Copy File task** in your release to achieve this.

Specify the artifact what you want to work with in release pipeline, and copy it from `File A`(the source file where these build artifacts is) to `File B`(any file you want). And then, you can do other thing with this specific build.

[image]

Hope this could help -)